# Locales with independent language and country

Tags: localization, plugin-elementapi, headless

How might we use Craft to manage our locales, keeping our language and country logic independent? The desired scenario:

- No duplicate language entries: Spanish in Spain would be the same as Spanish in Mexico or Portugal or China.
- Content sections should be shown or hidden based on country.

We are running Craft headless with React, so this question is more about how to most efficiently manage our data in Craft and whether or not Craft can (or should) handle the locale routing.

Perhaps we would be better off putting the show/hide logic and locale routing in React.